# c# character encoding that treats accented characters like simple ones

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, utf

Is there an encoding where an accented character like á or ä is treated as a single character?
and if not then what would be the most commonly used encoding today? I'm using UTF7 currently, how compatible is that with other types of encoding?

Thanks

Comment: I believe any UTF encoding can store `á` as both single code point and a combination of `a` and a diacritic surrogate. Are you not confusing encodings with collations? Or characters with code points? Or code points with encoded string data? See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might think about what you're asking for. You're asking for an encoding that will recognize 'á' and turn it into 'a'. That's a converter, not an encoding. It would have to know what encoding the source is in so that it can convert to whatever encoding you're using.

Wait, maybe that's not what you're asking. There *are* encodings that treat those as single bytes. For example, the [ISO-8859-1 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (also called Latin-1) treats many accented characters as a single byte.

(The following struck out because I was talking about ASCII, not UTF-7 ... long day.)

<strike>UTF-7 isn't particularly compatible with many other encodings. It has 128 possible values: just enough space for the 52 letters (upper and lower case, combined) used in the Latin alphabet, the 10 numerals, 32 control characters, and various punctuation marks. But it's not sufficient for Spanish, for example, which has upside-down questions marks and exclamation points as well as other things.</strike>

[UTF-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) is "compatible" with other encodings in that it can represent the entire Unicode character set. But only some characters (known as the "direct characters") and a few control characters can be directly encoded as single ASCII bytes. Those characters will be the same as in UTF-8 and in many single-byte character sets. All other characters are represented by sequences, and will be different from any other encoding.

The most commonly used encoding today? On the Web, UTF-8 is used a lot. It's also the default encoding used when you create a `StreamWriter`. For the work I do (mostly English, and Western European character sets), it works better than anything else.

Now, it's possible that what you're looking for is something that will treat 'á' and 'a' as the same in comparisons. That's a different question. See [Performing Culture-Insensitive String Comparisons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/885e1sy1.aspx) for information on that.

Comment: Almost all encodings can encode á as a single *character*. It may however be several bytes. á can be a single character or the letter a followed by a combining diacritic

Comment: @noggin182: Noted, and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with encodings. In C# it doesn't matter what encoding you use for storage and transmission, the strings of characters are always internally in UTF-16 and `ä` is always 1 char long in composed form.

If `"ä".Length` is giving `2` to you, your string is in decomposed form and all you need to do is

```
string str = "ä"; //a + U+0308, .Length == 2
str = str.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC); //just ä now, with Length == 1
```

Comment: Thanks for all of you for the help! I'm really just a beginner at this so i guess this shows how much i still need to learn...
You all helped a lot!

Comment: @WolfyD was my answer wrong? You unaccepted it and accepted the other  completely different answer which contradicts mine.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, as I said I'm new to this. Actually your answer was right for what i asked the problem is i asked the wrong thing, and while your answer is right it didn't solve my problem.

Your answer did make `label1.Text = utf8.GetBytes(x).Length.ToString();` to equal 1, but what i didn't realize is that that was not my main problem.

The program I'm working on has to return a MD5 hash value for the string, and it turns out that my real problem was mainly that I've been using `utf8` instead of an ISO set.

Again sorry, and thank you, your answer did help me understand some things.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion over this issue, i finally found what i was looking for, which is that i needed my text to use Windows-1250 (Central European (Windows)) code page, because that is what a lot of other programs use, that correctly support characters like €đłŁ¤...etc

Thanks for all the help i got, it was a useful learning experience.